# Angular 7: localhost route works, after deploy when update on route => not found

Tags: angular, deployment, angular7, angular-router

Routes on localhost works, and I can access also from route not only from index
www.myhost.com/route1 works on localhost
www.myhost.com => www.myhost.com/route1 works on my home server (I have public ip)
www.myhost.com/route1 doesn't work => give me NOT FOUND

I build with ng build --prod --watch
I try PathLocationStrategy
I try APP_BASE_HREF
I try LocationStrategy

base is set to "/"

I try useHash and it works but is really ugly.

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: MatchListComponent},
  {path: 'match/:id', component: MatchDetailComponent},
  {path: 'team/:id', component: TeamDetailComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MatchListComponent,
    MatchDetailComponent,
    TeamDetailComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    NgbModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {scrollPositionRestoration : 'enabled'})
  ],
  providers: [{provide: PathLocationStrategy}],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I try some solution for angular 2 or 4 but they don't work.
My web server is Apache2

Comment: So does useHash work?

Answer (score 0):

We can overcome this problem by using hash strategy

Hope it helps.

```
 RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
          useHash: true
        })
      ],
```

Comment: I say, before code, that hashStrategy is really ugly and it is not good for SEO

Comment: @Bluex then use web.config file here's the link https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2885

Comment: Ok, I try web.config. If It works I write here. I still need  “patchMatch:full” ?

Comment: yeah, pathMatch is needed

Comment: Nothing. Web.config doesn't work. If I navigate from a route to another it's ok, but if I do the access directly on a route like www.mysite.it/match, browser give me "Not Found The requested URL /match was not found". Why is so difficult a simple deployment

Answer (score 0):

Another option that can be used, if you are using Spring (or some other endpoint technology), is defining a controller that redirects all routes in your angular  application to the index.html file. Example:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping({
  "/login",
  "/clients",
  "/admin/users",
  "/admin/programs",
  "/reports",
  "/404"
})
class AppController {
  @GetMapping
  String admin() {
    return "../static/index";
  }
}
```